# Toggle button not working in other files except the homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a dark theme for a website. I have put a toggle button in the footer which is loaded on every page by using `<landing-footer></landing-footer>`.

The problem is that the toggle doesn't work on other pages and it also resets itself without reverting the effects it has when I change page.

I am pasting my footer.html and homepage and the page I tested it on.

**footer.html**

```
<footer class="ev-md-container ev-footer ev-dark-bg">
<div class="grad-container rm-grad-pad">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col l6 s12">
            <h5 class="white-text">EvalAI</h5>
            <p class="text-light-gray">Evaluating state of the art in AI</p>
            <ul class="inline-list">
                <li><a class="text-light-gray" href="https://github.com/Cloud-CV/EvalAI" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
                <li><a class="text-light-gray" href="https://twitter.com/project_cloudcv" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li>
                <div class="switch">
                    <label class="darktheme_text">
                        <input  type="checkbox" id="switch" name="theme">
                        <span class="lever"></span>
                        Dark Mode
                    </label>
                </div>
                </li>
                <!-- <li><a class="text-light-gray" href="#!"><i class="fa fa-facebook" target="_blank"></i></a></li> -->
            </ul>
            <p><a class="text-white">© CloudCV {{year}}</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col l4 offset-l0 s12">
            <h5 class="white-text">Links</h5>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="text-light-gray" ui-sref="about-us">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-light-gray" ui-sref="contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-light-gray" ui-sref="our-team">Our Team</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-light-gray" ui-sref="get-involved">Get Involved</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-light-gray" ui-sref="privacy_policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-light-gray" href="https://cloudcv.org">CloudCV Website</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col l2 s12">
            <h5 class="white-text">Stats</h5>
            <ul>
                <li>
                   <a class="github-button" href="https://github.com/Cloud-CV/EvalAI" data-icon="octicon-star" data-size="large" data-show-count="true" aria-label="Star Cloud-CV/EvalAI on GitHub">Star</a>
                 </li>
                <li>
                   <a class="github-button" href="https://github.com/Cloud-CV/EvalAI/fork" data-icon="octicon-repo-forked" data-size="large" data-show-count="true" aria-label="Fork Cloud-CV/EvalAI on GitHub">Fork</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</footer>
<script>
var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[name=theme]');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
if(this.checked) {
    trans()
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark')
} else {
    trans()
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light')
}
})
let trans = () => {
document.documentElement.classList.add('transition');
window.setTimeout(() => {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove('transition')
}, 1000)
}
</script>
```

**landing.html**

```
<div class="white-bg view-container flex-body">
<main-header></main-header>
<div class="content">
    <!-- EvalAI into -->
    <div class="grad-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m8 l8">
                <div class="grad-head">
                    <h3 class="text-dark-black"><strong>Evaluating state-of-the-art in AI</strong></h3>
                    <p class="text-med-black fs-18 w-300">EvalAI is an open source platform for evaluating and
                        comparing machine learning (ML) and artificial intelligence algorithms (AI) at scale.</p>
                    <div class="landing-buttons">
                        <ul class="inline-list">
                            <li>
                                <a ng-click="main.hostChallenge()" href="javascript:void(0)"
                                    class="dark-link theme"><strong>Host Challenge</strong></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a class="btn ev-btn-dark waves-effect waves-dark grad-btn grad-btn-dark fs-14"
                                    ui-sref="web.challenge-main">Participate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <section class="ev-container ev-details text-med-black ev-super-light-bg" id="ev-scroll-down">
        <div class="grad-container text-med-black ">
            <div class="row">
                <h4 class="w-300 center">Features</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 m2 l2">
                    <img src="/dist/images/features/protocols.png" alt="" width="100%">
                </div>
                <div class="col s12 m4 l4">
                    <h5 class="w-300">Custom evaluation protocol</h5>
                    <p class="w-300 fs-16">We allow creation of an arbitrary number of evaluation phases
                        and dataset splits, compatibility using any programming language, and organizing results in
                        both
                        public and private leaderboards.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col s12 m2 l2">
                    <img src="/dist/images/features/remote.png" alt="" width="100%">
                </div>
                <div class="col s12 m4 l4">
                    <h5 class="w-300">Remote evaluation</h5>
                    <p class="w-300 fs-16">Certain large-scale challenges need special compute capabilities for
                        evaluation. If the challenge needs extra computational power, challenge organizers can
                        easily add their own cluster of worker nodes to process participant submissions while we
                        take care of hosting the challenge, handling user submissions, and maintaining the
                        leaderboard.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 m2 l2">
                    <img src="/dist/images/features/docker.png" alt="" width="100%">
                </div>
                <div class="col s12 m4 l4">
                    <h5 class="w-300">Evaluation inside RL environments</h5>
                    <p class="w-300 fs-16">EvalAI lets participants submit code for their agent in the form of
                        docker images which are evaluated against test environments on the evaluation server. During
                        evaluation, the worker fetches the image, test environment, and the model snapshot and spins
                        up a new container to perform evaluation.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col s12 m2 l2">
                    <img src="/dist/images/features/cli.png" alt="" width="100%">
                </div>
                <div class="col s12 m4 l4">
                    <h5 class="w-300">CLI support</h5>
                    <p class="w-300 fs-16">EvalAI-CLI is designed to extend the functionality of the EvalAI web
                        application to your command line to make the platform more accessible and terminal-friendly.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 m2 l2">
                    <img src="/dist/images/features/portability.png" alt="" width="100%">
                </div>
                <div class="col s12 m4 l4">
                    <h5 class="w-300">Portability</h5>
                    <p class="w-300 fs-16">EvalAI was designed with keeping in mind scalability and portability of
                        such a system from the very inception of the idea. Most of the components rely heavily on
                        open-source technologies – Docker, Django, Node.js, and PostgreSQL.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col s12 m2 l2">
                    <img src="/dist/images/features/faster-eval.png" alt="" width="100%">
                </div>
                <div class="col s12 m4 l4">
                    <h5 class="w-300">Faster evaluation</h5>
                    <p class="w-300 fs-16">We warm-up the worker nodes at start-up by importing the challenge code
                        and pre-loading the dataset in memory. We also split the dataset into small chunks that are
                        simultaneously evaluated on multiple cores. These simple tricks result in faster evaluation
                        and reduces the evaluation time by an order of magnitude in some cases.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="ev-container ev-reverse-details text-med-black " id="ev-scroll-down">
        <div class="grad-container text-med-black ">
            <div class="row">
                <h4 class="w-300 center">Popular challenges</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 m3 l3" ng-repeat="challenge in main.challengeList.results track by $index"
                    ng-if="$index < 4"><a class="ev-card-hover"
                        ui-sref="web.challenge-main.challenge-page({challengeId:challenge.id})">
                        <div class="card ev-card-panel ev-challenge-card ev-card-hover">
                            <div class="card-image ev-card-image">
                                <img class="bg-img" ng-src="{{challenge.image}}">
                                <span class=" ev-card-title fs-14"><span><img
                                            ng-src="{{challenge.image}}"></span>{{challenge.title}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <p><strong class="text-light-black fs-12">Organized by</strong>
                                    <br>
                                    <span class="w-300 fs-16">{{challenge.creator.team_name}}</span>
                                </p>
                                <p><strong class="text-light-black fs-12">Starts on</strong>
                                    <br>
                                    <span class="w-300 fs-16">{{challenge.start_date | date:'medium'}}</span>
                                </p>
                                <p><strong class="text-light-black fs-12">Ends on</strong>
                                    <br>
                                    <span class="w-300 fs-16">{{challenge.end_date | date:'medium'}}</span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class=" btn-card-detail waves-effect waves-dark w-300 fs-14"> <strong>View Details
                                </strong> &nbsp; </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div ng-if="!main.challengeList.count" class="row">
                    <p class="text-dark-black w-300 center fs-16">Sorry! there are no featured challenges. Please
                        check again later.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- organizatons section -->
    <section class="ev-container ev-reverse-details text-med-black ev-super-light-bg " id="ev-scroll-down">
        <div class="grad-container text-med-black ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class="w-300 center">Partner Organizations</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/aptiv.png" id="aptiv-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/cmu.png" id="cmu-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/draper.png" id="draper-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/ebay.png" id="ebay-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/fb.png" id="fb-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/gt.png" id="gt-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/google.png" id="google-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/ibm.png" id="ibm-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/illinois.png" id="uiuc-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/iitm.png" id="iitm-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/intel.png" id="intel-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/ju.png" id="ju-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/mapillary.png" id="mapillary-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/mit.png" id="mit-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/nu.png" id="nu-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/siop.png" id="siop-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/stanford.png" id="stanford-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/adelaide.png" id="adelaide-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/umbc.png" id="umbc-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/pitt.png" id="pitt-logo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 l2">
                            <div class="org-logo">
                                <img src="dist/images/organizations/vt.png" id=vt-logo>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Arxiv Entry -->
    <section class="ev-container ev-reverse-details text-med-black " id="ev-scroll-down">
        <div class="grad-container text-med-black ">
            <div class="row">
                <h4 class="w-300 center">Cite our work</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
                    <h5 class="w-400">EvalAI: Towards Better Evaluation Systems for AI Agents</h5>
                    <span class="w-300 fs-16">Deshraj Yadav, Rishabh Jain, Harsh Agrawal, Prithvijit Chattopadhyay,
                        Taranjeet Singh, Akash Jain, Shiv Baran Singh, Stefan Lee, Dhruv Batra</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <a href="https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.03570" target="_blank">
                    <img src="dist/images/evalai-paper.jpg" alt="" width="100%" class="thumb">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<landing-footer></landing-footer>
```

**page i tested(challenge-page.html)**

```
<div class="white-bg view-container flex-body">
<main-header></main-header>
<div class="content">
    <div class="grad-container grad-vh">
        <div class="col s12 m6 ">
            <section class="ev-sm-container ev-view challenge-container">
                <div class="ev-md-container ev-card-panel ev-z-depth-5 challenge-title-container ">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s12 m3 l2">
                            <div class="image-container">
                                <img src="{{featured_challenge.page.image}}" width="100%">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col m9 l10">
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <p><span class="fs-18"><strong>{{featured_challenge.page.title}}</strong></span>
                                    <br>
                                    <span ng-if="featured_challenge.page.creator.team_url != ''"><strong class="text-light-black">Organized by:</strong><a class="orange-text" href="{{featured_challenge.page.creator.team_url}}" target="_blank"> {{featured_challenge.page.creator.team_name}} </a></span>
                                    <span ng-if="featured_challenge.page.creator.team_url == ''"><strong class="text-light-black">Organized by:</strong> {{featured_challenge.page.creator.team_name}} </span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row rm-row-bot">
                        <div class="col s12">
                            <ul class="inline-list rm-gut">
                                <li><a ui-sref=".overview" ui-sref-active="active-challenge" class="text-light-black w-500"><i class="fa fa-info"></i> Overview</a></li>
                                <li><a ui-sref=".evaluation" ui-sref-active="active-challenge" class="text-light-black w-500"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Evaluation</a></li>
                                <li><a ui-sref=".phases" ui-sref-active="active-challenge" class="text-light-black w-500"><i class="fa fa-level-up"></i> Phases</a></li>
                                <li ng-if="!featured_challenge.isParticipated"><a ui-sref=".participate" ui-sref-active="active-challenge" class="text-light-black w-500"><i class="fa fa-free-code-camp"></i> Participate</a></li>
                                <li><a ui-sref=".leaderboard" ui-sref-active="active-challenge" class="text-light-black w-500"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i> Leaderboard</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <ui-view></ui-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<landing-footer></landing-footer>
```

As per the script writtin in the footer it should add data-theme = 'dark' in html . i do it in the main landing page . but it is not working in other pages .

Comment: Are you using a cookie or something persistent to indicate the user wants dark-mode enabled across page changes?

Comment: no how can i do that?

Comment: Cookies (and local storage) have been documented to the ends of the earth. You'll want to research that yourself. JavaScript isn't persistent across pages.

Comment: Thx I will try it

Comment: Also, since you're using jQuery, you might look into how it can simplify your script.  `document.documentElement.classList.remove('transition')` can simply be `$(document).removeClass('transition')`, for example. Simplify further by creating variables for reused elements: `let docEl = $(document)`.